# Como hacer una lista numerada con letra de la a a la d y de la g a la j? yo hice lo siguiente pero no funciono

Tags: html

tengo que realizar una lista que sea de la g a la j yo realice lo siguiente:

```
<h4>La lista debe ir desde la laetra a hasta la d y otra desde la a hasta la j y otra de la z hasta w</h4>
<ol type="a">
<li>Elemento 1</li>
<li>Elemento 2</li>
<li>Elemento 3</li>
<li>Elemento 4</li>
</ol>
<ol type="g">
<li>Elemento 1</li>
<li>Elemento 2</li>
<li>Elemento 3</li>
<li>Elemento 4</li>
</ol>
```

Investigando entendi que debia darle el atributo type="g" a la segunda. Pero me devuelve una lista numerada con numeros.No se si entendi mal o que paso.La tercera lista directamente no supe como seria.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Debes utilizar `start` para poder iniciar la lista en algun valor diferente al inicial. `start` acepta números así que tendrás que poner el número de la letra que deseas según su posición en el abecedario.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Lista ordenada a partir de la G</h1>

<ol type="a" start="7">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo tu respuesta, vi lo del start pero pende que solo aplicaba a numeros. Gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta te recomiendo que la aceptes, así ayudas a otros usuarios con el mismo problema y ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas